# Replace html content with Javascript in GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Trying to replace "sofort lieferbar" with "Lieferung auf Bestellung" with javascript if class "availability stati13" in Google Tag Manager.

```
<div class="availability stati13" style="">
sofort lieferbar

            <div class="blueinfo">
        <div style="display: none; opacity: 1;">in den nächsten Tagen Versandbereit</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript itself works fine, but in GTM, nothing happens if fired with a custom html tag.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.querySelector(".availability.stati13").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace("sofort lieferbar", "Lieferung auf Bestellung");
  document.querySelector(".availability.stati13").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Does someone know, why this script in gtm isn't working?

GTM works fine, i tried this one:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/hello/g, 'hi');
```

That would work, but i can't create the if class requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define a function `myFunction()` but where do you execute it?
Maybe you should write it as a self executing function:

```
(function(){
    // your code here ...
})();
```

Also make sure to have this tag execute on Dom ready (in order for your code to find the elements you are looking for)

[dom-ready-trigger-in-google-tag-manager-quick-guide/](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/dom-ready-trigger-in-google-tag-manager-quick-guide/)

Also the line `document.querySelector(".availability.stati13")` will return only the first element!. If there are multiple DOM elements with this class you have to handle this for all of them with `querySelectorAll`.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".availability.stati13");    
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
  elements[i].innerHTML = str.replace("sofort lieferbar", "Lieferung auf Bestellung");
}
```

I used `for` instead of `forEach` for maximum compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for your help d3bgger,

I tried your option, unfortunately doesn't repleace the text. Trigger is firing on Dom ready.


<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
  var str = document.querySelector(".availability.stati13").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace("sofort lieferbar", "Lieferung auf Bestellung");
  document.querySelector(".availability.stati13").innerHTML = res;
})();
</script>

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? Try adding some console logs in your code to see the   values, or if it is executed at all.

Comment: Couldn't find something in the console. -> https://www.googletagmanager.com/start_preview/gtm?uiv2&id=GTM-N9ZWMD&check_preview_status=1&gtm_auth=CbJ9wdwUYKU_X0vVPay6Sg&gtm_preview=env-84&gtm_debug=x&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fust.ch%2Fde%2Fr%2Fhaushalt%2Fbabyartikel-895.html

Comment: Oh i see that there are multiple divs with the class ".availability.stati13". You should change your code to iterate in all of the divs! I will edit my answer to support that.

Comment: You are my hero! <3 Thanks 100 times for your support and help! - it works!!