# Replacing a text inside of a div in GTM

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61280988/replace-html-content-with-javascript-in-gtm/61281174#61281174?newreg=98b23d3434754c77b514a6088f3fd50f) I want to change some text inside a dynamic div. The explanation there didn't work for me so I started a new thread (rep too low to comment). What makes this div "dynamic" is a some script that calculate how much money you need to spend (based on added to cart items) to get free shipping. The statement I want to replace is always there. I guess you could call it erasing the part of the text. :)

My div:

```
<div class="free-shipping__content">Brakuje Ci 151,00&nbsp;zł do darmowej dostawy (Paczkomaty InPost).</div>
```

My code in GTM (loaded on DOM ready):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
  var elements = document.querySelectorALL(".free_shipping__content");    
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
    elements[i].innerHTML = str.replace(" (Paczkomaty InPost)", "");
}
})();
</script>
```

Thanks!

[Image of surrounding divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REvXr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Good job on that closure.
2. `document.querySelectorALL` is not a function. You meant `document.querySelectorAll`.
3. Another problem is your css selector. You're using `.free_shipping__content` while the actual class name is different. Your selector should be `.free-shipping__content`

After these fixes, your code works. However, I already rewrote it to test properly, so I might as well offer a more readable and elegant solution:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".free-shipping__content").forEach(function (el) {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(" (Paczkomaty InPost)", "");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked perfectly, was so close! Your other solution is definitely more elegant and works like a charm!