# Replacing text inside of multiple divs on a page via GTM

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

Similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022267/replacing-a-text-inside-of-a-div-in-gtm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61280988/replace-html-content-with-javascript-in-gtm/61281174#61281174?newreg=98b23d3434754c77b514a6088f3fd50f), I need to change some text inside of a div on a page using GTM.

I've followed previous help posted in the aforementioned threads which has been great, allowing me to get a text change implemented for a pop-up loading message as users navigate through a form style flow of checking their postcode, selecting a package, and checking out.

Unfortunately when I try call this script again but target a different element on the page, the functionality of the page breaks and the user is unable to progress 'next' or click on any of the selectable packages on the screen. It feels like the problem is caused by calling the same script twice (unless I'm wrong), so I'm looking for a way to amend the script to edit different sections of the page within that one script.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, I'm a complete javascript novice!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".txt");    
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
    elements[i].innerHTML = str.replace("Loading...", "Searching.. please allow 20 seconds.");
}
})();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function (){
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".site");    
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
    elements[i].innerHTML = str.replace("Free standard connection", "First 3 months free");
}
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Does the break give you any console error in the devtool ? Or just some how the user can not click the next button. If you pause these js then the issue is gone?

Comment: You dont should use innerHTML all Events will lost added before to the element. Also you can put the functions in one together